# if $a^5+b^5<1$ and $c^5+d^5<1$ then prove that ${a^2}{c^3}+{b^2}{d^3}<1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, proof-writing

if $a^5+b^5<1$ and $c^5+d^5<1$ then prove that ${a^2}{c^3}+{b^2}{d^3}<1$ given $a,b,c,d$ are non  negative real numbers

**My try:**
It is easy to deduce that $a,b,c,d<1$ ,thus

$$a^2c^3+b^2d^3<a^5c^5+b^5d^5<(a^5+b^5)(c^5+d^5)<1$$

I want to know if there is a more cleaner method to solve this problem and if possible with calculus. I would also  want to know if my proof has a mistake anywhere.

Comment: Yes, there is a mistake: since $0<a<1$, we have $a^2 > a^5$, not $a^2<a^5$ (and similarly for the other variables); so your first inequality is invalid. Do you know Hölder's inequality?

Comment: oh thank you !  ,,and i dont know holders inequality ! This came as a part of calculus based questions

Comment: Seems Lagrange Multiplier can be useful. Is it allowed?

Comment: @cr$0001$ i am very new to inequalities  so i haven't even heard of that term

Comment: In calculus, this kind of constraint maximization is generally solved with that method. But never mind if you have not learned it yet. Maybe there are some other clever way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is wrong in the first step: $$a^2c^3+b^2d^3\geq a^5c^5+b^5d^5.$$

By Holder $$1>(a^5+b^5)^2(c^5+d^5)^3\geq(a^2c^3+b^2d^3)^5.$$
We can prove the last inequality by the following way.

If $abcd=0$, so our inequality is obvious.

Let $abcd\neq0$, $a=xb$ and $c=yd$.

Thus, we need to prove that $$(x^5+1)^2(y^5+1)^3\geq(x^2y^3+1)^5$$ or $f(x)\geq0,$ where $$f(x)=2\ln(x^5+1)+3\ln(y^5+1)-5\ln(x^2y^3+1).$$
But $$f'(x)=\frac{10x^4}{x^5+1}-\frac{10xy^3}{x^2y^3+1}=\frac{10x(x^3-y^3)}{(x^5+1)(x^2y^3+1)},$$
which gives $x_{min}=y$, $$f(x)\geq f(y)=0$$ and we are done!

Comment: is there a way to prove this without the holder inequality (i havent learnt about it yet)

Comment: @Hari Ramakrishnan Sudhakar About Holder see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/5773

Comment: @Hari Ramakrishnan Sudhakar There is a very ugly way by using a full expanding. Also, if you know derivatives, so I have found something simple. But it would be better if you'll learn Holder.

Comment: yes  i know about derivatives could you help me with that ,Thanks!

Comment: @Hari Ramakrishnan Sudhakar I added something. See now.

Comment: Very nice reduction of $4$ variables to just $1$. Never thought this is even possible.

Comment: @HariRamakrishnanSudhakar I think context is critical here.  Did you personally include the "holder-inequality" tag?  If so, does this mean that you have been studying it in class?  If not, what theorems or recently confronted math problems, that you regard a pertinent, lead up to your being assigned this problem?  You make a good point that it is plausible that use of the holder inequality was not the *intended solution.*  However, in order to find the intended solution, you will need to provide **very detailed context.**  ...see next comment.

Comment: @HariRamakrishnanSudhakar I suggest that (if feasible) you check with your teacher for a hint/guide re the intended solution.  Then, if relevant, I suggest that you create a new mathSE query.  In this new query, show the problem's context in as much detail as possible, show as much work as you can re the (speculatively) intended solution, and provide a link to this query in your new query.  Then, you can add a brief addendum to this posting re "see <mathSE link to new posting> for investigation of what solution is **intended.**

Comment: @user2661923 Following this question from the beginning, I think what the original poster wanted was a Calculus-based solution using only property of derivatives, like this answer provided. The tag was added later on by someone else for searching convenience I guess.

Comment: @user2661923 the holder inequality was not added by me.It came when the question was editted

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg thanks a lot  for the calculus based proof! As you had mentioned earlier i will make it a point to learn holder too

Comment: @Hari Ramakrishnan Sudhakar You are welcome! See also the beautiful nguyenhuyen_ag's solution.

Comment: @cr001 "I think what the original poster wanted was a Calculus-based solution using only property of derivatives, like this answer provided." Nice rebuttal, interesting perspective.

Answer (score 5):

Using the AM-GM inequality, we have
$$2a^5 + 3c^5 \geqslant 5\sqrt[5]{(a^5)^2 \cdot (c^5)^3} = 5a^2 c^3,$$
similar
$$ 2b^5 + 3d^5 \geqslant 5b^2 d^3.$$
Therefore
$$5(a^2c^3+b^2d^3) \leqslant 2(a^5+b^5)+3(c^5+d^5).$$
But $$2(a^5+b^5)+3(c^5+d^5) < 2 \cdot 1 +3\cdot 1 = 5.$$
So
$$a^2c^3+b^2d^3 \leqslant 1.$$
Done.

Comment: thanks! never thought the problem can be solved simply using weighted AM-GM inequality